# Adding CSS to a block created in admin side in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created css to a block in magento 2 admin side. I want to add css to it .
Is there any standard way to do this beside using style tags?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 using [Less as css processor](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html).

To add some css, **you need write code at less files then magento2** own less converte **convert this less code css** .

As you want too add **some css to admin area** then suggesting to you create `a custom module` .Then create a **`_module.less`** at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/view/adminhtml/web/css/source` and write **the css on this  to less structure**.

After that do static content deploy for**strong text** you reflect your changes.

**Your module should have below files**

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`.
2. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
3. . `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.json`.